# How to calculate the integral of a product of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion

I search an alternate expression for

> **∫*f*(x)*g*(x)**

I'd like to express it in terms of $f$ and $g$ and $n$-th derivatives and antiderivatives of $f$ and $g$.

For example, I could use something like this: (if it where a solution)

**f'**(x)+**F**(x)**g**(x)-5**g'**(x)x+ln(x)

I don't mind if those terms are "of infinite length". (like for example a Taylor series)

However, I would prefer a "finite term" as solution. (regardless of its length)

I doubt that there is a solution to this in form of a "finite term", using only $f$ and $g$ and $n$th derivatives and antiderivatives of $f$ and $g$, because that would render the partial integration quite useless.

I cannot use solutions containing any Integrals over "composite terms".

like, for example:

∫f(x)g(x)dx=F(x)g(x)-**∫F(x)g'(x)dx**

If the solution uses a Taylor series, I'd like to know when exactly this solution can be employed, because as far as I know, a taylor series does not always converge.

similarly, if the solution uses any other infinite series approaching the result, Id like to know under wich circumstances it can be applied, too. (are there any cases where the series used does not converge?)

Comment: Search for "integration by parts".

Comment: I am aware of that method, but it does not solve the problem because the "solution" contains ∫F(x)g'(x)dx,an integral over some composite term, so you basically end up where you started, because you dont have concrete f and g, f and g are variables.

Comment: As a short-cut to integration by-parts, you could try "tabular integration", or the "Stand and Deliver" method. It's just an organized way to do integration by-parts, but you might find it useful.

Comment: the problem here is that these methods seem to do integration by parts until one of the factors in the composite integral ∫F(x)g'(x)dx becomes zero so that the whole integral becomes zero. I want to use this as a little part in a whole to find some g(x) dependent on f(x) and some condition. However, because g(x) is to be found, i cannot make many assumptions about it. I just assume that it is "perfectly smooth". (differentiable infinite many times) as f(x) is given, I could choose f(x) in a way that such an approach works, but i'd rather find a better solution than messing with the premisses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only known solution to your problem is integration by parts and you do not like it .

Other than that you need restrictions on $f$ and $g$ to try substitution .

In special cases such as polynomials or some trig functions you may find answers but in general the problem is too broad to be solved.

Comment: how about series? I expected that there is no "finite length" term solution, but how about infinite length terms, such as series, any way to use them here?

Comment: Yes, you may approximate your functins with series or if you are lucky you find a closed form for the integral of product of series.